# MPMusicPlayer Setup

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

Im setting up an MPMusicPlayer. Simple controls right now. Play, back, forward. I have three IBActions linked up. For play, its not working. I believe I had it working once. For the setQueue, I tried two ways. One was to give it songs(). Another was to do songs().items and add it to the mediaCollection then pass it to setQueue. Neither work.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController()
    let songItems = MPMediaQuery.songs()
    //let testItems = MPMediaQuery

    func setUp(){

        //let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: songItems!)
        musicPlayer.setQueue(with: songItems)
        musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func skipBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if musicPlayer.isPreparedToPlay{
            musicPlayer.play()}
        testLabel.text = "pressed"
    }

    @IBAction func skipForward(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        /*
        //Music Access
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            if status == .authorized {
                self.setUp()
            } else {
                print("maybe later g")
            }
        }

    */
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

1. cheout if device is in vibration mode.
2. Use AVAudioPlayer  for audio files as it's recommended by apple